# React Native - ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers in not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I was using react-navigation 1.2.1 and every thing was working fine as soon as I updated react-navigation to 2.0.0 it gives the following error. Any idea why it must be happening?

> ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers in not a function.

```
import * as ReactNavigation from 'react-navigation';

render() {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
    const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch,
      state: nav,
      addListener,
    });

    return <AppNavigation navigation={navigation} />;
  }

//"react-navigation": "2.0.0",
//"react-native": "0.53.3",
//"redux": "^3.7.2"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems that `addNavigationHelpers` has been removed from `react-navigation's` default exports, which can be seen [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/src/react-navigation.js).

Therefore as mentioned in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html), you need to directly add to the `navigation` props as

```
<AppNavigator navigation={{
   dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
   state: this.props.nav,
   addListener,
}} />
```

Comment: This answer is probably outdated I don't see anything about `addNavigationHelpers` or about `navigation prop` in the docs link.

Comment: Hi @PritishVaidya, This gives me an error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.routes')` Any leads on that?