# React Native - addnavigationHelpers is undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am fairly new to react-native and have been hitting the following error while trying to set up my appNavigation along with redux.

**TypeError: (0, _reactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers)({dispatch:dispatch, state: nav})' (0, _reactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers)' is undefined.**

*Code* -->

> App.js -

```
import React from 'react';

import store from './src/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import AppNavigation from './src/components/AppNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppNavigation />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

> AppNavigator.js -

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoApp from '../TodoApp';
import TodoDetails from '../components/TodoDetails';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

export const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        todoDetails: TodoDetails,
        home: TodoApp,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'todoDetails',
    },
);

const AppNavigation = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
    <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })} />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    nav :state.nav,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppNavigation);
```

EDIT -

I did follow the steps given at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246457/react-native-reactnavigation-addnavigationhelpers-in-not-a-function`

But unfortunately, that gives an error saying

**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.routes')**

The error is located at:
  in Navigator (at AppNavigator.js:20)
  in AppNavigation (created by ConnectFunction)
  in ConnectFunction (at App.js:19)......

[image: Error received on changing the code as per other StackOverflow answer link]

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246457/react-native-reactnavigation-addnavigationhelpers-in-not-a-function

Comment: Don't use Redux to store your navigation state https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html#can-i-store-the-navigation-state-in-redux-too

Answer (score 0):

`addNavigationHelpers` has been removed from react-navigation's default exports,

you need to directly add to the `navigation` props as

```
<AppNavigator navigation={{
   dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
   state: this.props.nav,
   addListener,
}} />
```

A great answer by pritish , hope it help.s

Comment: Already tried the answer @gaurav-roy. but, this gives an error stating 
```undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.routes')```

Comment: where have you used the state.routes?

Comment: I Haven't @gaurav-roy. I will update the error image in the question
Done.